# In an array of dates how to find closest previous date from a given date (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array with dates three days apart i.e. 10th Feb, 13th Feb, 16th Feb and so on.

`var givenDate = new Date();`

`givenDate.setDate(12);`

In the array above, I want to find the closest previous date from the givenDate 
- so the answer should be 10th Feb (as it is the closest previous date to 12th Feb).

I found this in one of the forums to get the nearest date:

```
var bestDate = dates.length; // dates is the name of my array

var bestDiff = -(new Date(0,0,0)).valueOf();

var currDiff = 0;

var i;

for(i = 0; i < dates.length; ++i){

   currDiff = Math.abs(between[i] - testDate);

   if(currDiff < bestDiff){

       bestDate = i;

       bestDiff = currDiff;

   }   
}

// the best date will be days[bestDate] 

document.write(dates[bestDate]);
```

The problem with this is it gives the nearest date which could be the next date instead of previous. Like for 12th Feb, it would give 13th Feb instead of 10th Feb.

Thank you.

Comment: Transform the date into un number by doying `(new Date()).getTime()` if the difference is positive you disregard and you look for the smallest difference.

Answer (score 5):

1) Sort in reverse order so that (16th come first and 10th last from sample dates)

2) Use `find` method on above sorted array to get the closest prev date in available dates.

Update: Thank you @RobG thats great to know.

@Masoom, Instead of using `find`, use `findIndex` to get the index of date. Then you can easily next one.
PS. You will need to make sure edge cases and accessing out of bound indexes. (findIndex will return -1 when not found or when prev date is `0` index, then will not have any next day)

```js
const dates = [
  new Date(2020, 1, 10),
  new Date(2020, 1, 13),
  new Date(2020, 1, 16)
];

const my_date = new Date(2020, 1, 12);

const prev_date_index = dates
  .sort((a, b) => (b - a))
  .findIndex(date => date - my_date <= 0);
  
const prev_date = dates[prev_date_index];
const next_date = dates[prev_date_index - 1];

console.log(prev_date.toDateString());
console.log(next_date.toDateString());
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much. How about if I want the next_date? Like in my array of 10th, 13th, 16th : if my_date is 12th, I want to retrieve the next closest date in the array (13th).

Comment: @MasoomGilani, Updated the answer slightly to get the next date.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've chosen isn't suitable for the reason you state, and your solution can be much simpler. You want to find the last date that is before your date, so just subtract each date from the test date and when the result is 0 or negative, the previous date is the one you want.

You should also deal with out of bounds values, e.g. before the start or after the end. I've guessed what you want in those cases, you need to consider what needs to be done and adjust the logic to suit.

E.g.

```js
// Get last element of arr that is before d
function getPrevious(d, arr) {
  let i = 0;
  while (d - arr[i] > 0 && i < arr.length - 1) {
    i++;
  }
  return i == 0? void 0 : arr[--i] ;
}

// Sample data
let dates = [
  new Date(2020, 1, 10), // 2020-02-10
  new Date(2020, 1, 13), // 2020-02-13
  new Date(2020, 1, 16), // 2020-02-16 
  new Date(2020, 1, 19)  // 2020-02-19
];

// Test dates
[new Date(2020, 1,  8), // 2020-02-08 -> before start -> undefined
 new Date(2020, 1, 12), // 2020-02-12 -> within range -> 10 Feb
 new Date(2020, 2, 12)  // 2020-03-12 -> after end    -> last date
].forEach(d => {
  let result = getPrevious(d, dates);
  console.log(`${d.toDateString()} -> ${result? result.toDateString() : result}`)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- Sort
- getIndex and retrieve the value

```js
var datesArray = [new Date("02-10-2020"), new Date("02-13-2020"), new Date("02-16-2020")];

var newDateToInsert = new Date("02-12-2020");
datesArray.push(newDateToInsert);

datesArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
var index = (datesArray.indexOf(newDateToInsert) - 1) >= 0 ? datesArray.indexOf(newDateToInsert) - 1 : datesArray.indexOf(newDateToInsert);
console.log(datesArray[index]);
```

----EDIT----
you can clone this as well in the new array, something like given below to not change original array-

```
var datesArray = [new Date("02-10-2020"), new Date("02-13-2020"), new Date("02-16-2020")];

var newDateToInsert = new Date("02-12-2020");
var tempArray = [].concat(datesArray);
tempArray.push(newDateToInsert);

tempArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
var index = (tempArray.indexOf(newDateToInsert) - 1) >= 0 ? tempArray.indexOf(newDateToInsert) - 1 : tempArray.indexOf(newDateToInsert);
console.log(datesArray[index]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I am not interested in inserting my given_date to the array. I want my array to stay as it is but given a date, I would like to know which (previous) date in the array is closest to it. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @MasoomGilani I have added one small edit, hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

## Hi,

**Solution**

```
let dates = // --> your dates array
let givenDate = new Date();
let givenDateInMS = givenDate.getTime();

let prevTimeDiff = Infinity;
let closestDate = null;
dates.forEach((date, index) => {
 let timeInMS = date.getTime();
 let timeDiff = givenDateInMS - timeInMS;
 if((timeDiff > 0) && (timeDiff < prevTimeDiff)) {
    prevTimeDiff = timeDiff;
    closestDate = date;
 }
})

if(closestDate != null){
 // here you have it
 console.log(closestDate)
}else{
 //there is no prev closest date (all dates might be greater than given date)
}
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.